# how to use ramda to extract changed properties from an object, when compared against original

Tags: javascript, ramda.js

Hopefully using ramda, I would like to take the changes made to config, and use them to update a users config, where the property/ies changed have the same old value.

After discussion.   changes.   I will keep a changes object and just R.merge(original, user).   However I need to be able to extract a changed property and its value, so that i can merge that object, into the user, when on user config.

Example:

```js
var original = { name:'test', setting1:1, setting2:2 };
var toChange = R.clone(original);
var userConfig {};
/// edit toChange
toChange.setting1 = 2;
/// extract setting1 and value from toChange

R.difference(original,toChange) => should be { setting1:2 };
/// but this does not work,  no matter what way round i put original 
/// and toChange, need to extract that change / diff

/// so i can then
userConfig = R.merge(userConfig, R.difference(original,toChange)); // for example
```

Comment: I'm sure we could write a function to do this, but there seems to be a major flaw.  How do you decide that the user has just accepted the default rather than intentionally chosen the same value as the default?  So Sue says, "Settings 2 and 3, please", then changes her mind and says, "Never mind, I liked 1 & 2 better.  Change them back."  Do you really want to override this if you change the base settings?  (I know there quite likely are no actual people involved, but I assume the idea is clear.)

Comment: yeah good point, but users dont actually change these properties.   Its ensentially a config thats says things like SMS enabled, Email enabled.   the client would have a default for all users ( original ).   but may wish to control individually for a user, so new user = get current config ->  assign to user.  but client may say, okay enable SMS.  if someone had already enabled sms,  no effect,  all those still on false, would now be updated to true.  Does this make sense.   I have just tried difference, but that never worked.  Essentially need a diff

Comment: What Im trying to do here is avoid config getting out of sync with users, or prevent that admin, having to update each user manually to update enable SMS for example

Comment: But it's the same point.  Say the default starts as `enableSMS:true`. A user doesn't want this and the admin changes it to `false` for her.  Now the default changes to `false`; all is well and good, but business requirements change, and the default is set back to `true`.  Now these rules would change the value for this user to something she explicitly rejected.  Not good.

Comment: Why not simply keep the defaults in one place and each users' overrides in another, then `merge` them when you want to use them.  This keeps everything clear.  `defaults = { name:'test', setting1:'1', setting2:'2' }`, userSettings = [{name: 'bob'}, {name: 'rita', setting1: '3',}, {name: 'sue'}]`.  Then when you want to check the values for someone, `merge(defaults, userSettings[i])`?  Wouldn't that do?  And wouldn't it be more clear?

Comment: yeah this is usually how I have done it before.  a user custom settings table so to speak.  but was trying to work a new way, that wouldn't involve lookups ALL the time, especially on remote services.   figured if i can just push the diff, there is no need to always check if XYZ.  as the config of user, is the config!!!  :-)   I guess i should stop trying to be clever about it

Comment: on the other comment, only admin can change settings, user has no visibility of this, or choice.   so in my example.   client may say i aint gonna enable SMS,  but i will try on 3 people.   they happy that SMS works.   so they now want to globally update all the other 480 users with enable SMS.   I.E   just enable sms for their users.

Comment: so basically you're saying this:  
var original = { name: 'test', setting1: 1, setting2: 2 };
        var user = { setting2: 3 };
        console.log(R.merge(original, user));

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155928/discussion-between-davethecoder-and-scott-sauyet).

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm saying.  Keep the notion of defaults separate from user overrides and combine when necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a way to solve incase someone wants to do the same

```js
var orig = {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3};
var edited = R.merge(R.clone(orig),{b:7});
var user = { d: 4 };

//check if left value == right value
//if not, return null
//on merge with

//wrap around reject if null

//wrap around a merge into user

user = R.merge(user, R.reject(R.isNil, 
R.mergeWith(function(l,r){
  return (R.equals(l,r)) ? null : l;
},edited,orig)));

console.log(user);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.24.1/ramda.min.js"></script>
```